# Rotating A Single Rectangle in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this problem: I am making a game and I need to rotate a single rectangle (the blue one) between other rectangles.

Here is my code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

//Making The Canvas Fullscreen :
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

//The rectangle I Need To Rotate :
c.fillStyle = "blue"
c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)

c.fillStyle = "red"
c.fillRect(canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
c.fillRect(canvas.width*2/3, canvas.height*2/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
```

Any Solve ???

Comment: Have you Googled how to rotate yet? Also what is `c` in you code? It’s never assigned.

Comment: Friendly note, there's no need to capitalize every word in a sentence. How do you want to rotate it exactly? Usually I use `ctx.rotate`.

Comment: Hello ... First .. I searched for this in google but no sence , second, I mean with ```c``` the ```ctx``` but I forgot .... Third, thank you for your friendly note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to apply a transformation to only a limited set of drawing operations, you usually do:

- `ctx.save()` to save the initial state
- `ctx.transform()`, `.rotate`, `.translate`, `.skew` or `.scale` to apply your desired transformation
- run the drawing commands
- `ctx.restore()` to restore the initial state

So, to rotate your rectangle 30 degrees around `(0, 0)`, you would do:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight


ctx.save();
// 30 degree rotation around 0, 0
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6); 
ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
ctx.restore();

ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width*2/3, canvas.height*2/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you want to rotate around the rectangle's center, you could do:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight


ctx.save();

const w = canvas.width / 3;
const h = canvas.height / 3;
ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
ctx.fillRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
ctx.restore();

ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width*2/3, canvas.height*2/3,canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code snippets ... so here you saved the canvas image ... rotated the rectangle needed and restored it? wow !

Comment: It's more like you're rotating the coordinate system. Any drawn pixels before the transformation will stay where they are.